# Connect SAP HANA to Big Query using Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam, hana

I Need to Connect SAP HANA to Big Query using Apache Beam, Anyone has used hana-bq-beam-connector. I am currently using this [blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/using-apache-beam-and-cloud-dataflow-to-integrate-sap-hana-and-bigquery)

with this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/google/hana-bq-beam-connector)

It is a java maven project after opening it in eclipse and fixing the dependencies in the project (`pom.xml`), 
Could not Solve the Issues,

> Error : **"AutoValue cannot be resolved to a type - Eclipse"**

Did anyone use this Repo / Library? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the m2e-apt plugin fixed the problem.

And then go to maven preference and try to change setting for Automatically configure JDT apt .

[image: Screenshot For Maven Preference]